# How to use org.springframework.messaging.converter.ProtobufMessageConverter

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I was trying to use Spring framework built-in `ProtobufMessageConverter` to convert my kafka message but I couldn't seem to find a way to have this converter being used.

The configuration of my binding is as the following:

```
  bindings:
    input-in-0:
      destination: test-input
      group: test-group
      content-type: application/x-protobuf;charset=UTF-8
```

When I use my custom message converter, I can see it registered in `SimpleFunctionRegistry.messageConverter` which is a list of customer converter and default ones. However, `ProtobufMessageConverter` doesn't seem to be included in default converters (they are registered in `CompositeMessageConverterFactory.initDefaultConverters`) and also filtered out by `ContentTypeConfiguration.isConverterEligible` if I try to instantiate it manually.

I checked the official document but it doesn't mention how to properly use the converter.I would be grateful if anyone can share your experience on how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that it is registered in `SimpleFunctionRegistry.messageConverter` is enough. The `initDefaultConverters` is outdated functionality from the annotation-based support in s-c-stream and is not affecting you here (assuming you are using function-based programming model).

Anyway, in the list of converters in  `SimpleFunctionRegistry` your converter should be the first one and should be the first one to be tried by [SmartCompositeMessageConverter](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/blob/main/spring-cloud-function-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/function/context/config/SmartCompositeMessageConverter.java).
What I suspect is that something is wring with the implementation of your `ProtobufMessageConverter` since it does not respond to `application/x-protobuf;charset=UTF-8` content type when it test if this converter supports a particular message. But without seeing the implementation or having a reproducible sample it is hard to say what that may be. Perhaps you can create a bare minimum sample and push i to github somewhere so we can take a look?

Comment: Hi Oleg, thank you for your kind reply. What I would like to do is to use the default `ProtobufMessageConverter` instead of making my own version. However, I couldn't find a way to have it registered. It is not included in the default converters and is filtered out by `ContentTypeConfiguration.isConverterEligible`. That's where I get stuck into.

Comment: Just an FYI, that that particular configuration has no effect for the functional style.  That said, indeed there is similar method in `ContextFunctionCatalogAutoConfiguration` which filters out 'standard' converters. We do that because there were issues with users not wanting rogue converters added to the list of message converters. We probably need to figure out a different mechanism. That said, you can subvert it by simply subclassing `ProtobufMessageConverter`  (e.g., `public class MyProtobufMessageConverter extends ProtobufMessageConverter{}` and register it as `@Bean`.